# Magento 2.2.2: How to use Image file available in web folder

Tags: php, image, php-7, magento2.2.2

**Magento 2.2.2**

How to use Image file available in the web folder.
I am trying to access image file in layout/footer.phtml file and the image is available in the web/images/ folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try below code:**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/your-image-name.jpg'); ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: Welcome :) Please let me know what you did?